# Имя выбранного файла из html в php

Tags: php, html, файлы

Есть html с кнопкой выбора файла:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Поле загрузки файлов, которое мы заслужили</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <form id="upload-container" method="POST" action="index.php">
          <div>
               <input id="file-input" type="file" name="file" multiple>
          </div>
     </form>
     <form action="index.php" method="POST">
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Выполнить" />
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

И есть PHP в который нужно получить имя файла :

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']){
    $_FILES['userfile']['name']

include('выбор.html');
include ('наша.php');
echo '<pre>';
$kml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
foreach ($kml->Document->Folder->Placemark as $Placemark) {

        echo $Placemark->MultiGeometry->Polygon->outerBoundaryIs->LinearRing->coordinates, PHP_EOL;

    foreach ( $Placemark->ExtendedData->SchemaData as $SchemaData ) {
        foreach ( $SchemaData as $SimpleData ) {
            $name = $SimpleData->attributes()->name;
            if ( $name == 'TITLE' || $name == 'DESCRIPTIO' || $name == 'SHAPE_Area') {
                echo '<pre>';
                echo $SimpleData . PHP_EOL;
                echo '</pre>';
            }
        }
    }
}
}
?>
```

Как мне в PHP через `POST` получить имя выбранного файла?

Comment: Дополнил ответ. Ругается на {

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['submit'])){` - нужна скобка ещё одна

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пропущена круглая скобка в условии.
**Найди:**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']){
```

**Замени на:**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="my_file[]" multiple>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
    <?php
        if (isset($_FILES['my_file'])) {
            $myFile = $_FILES['my_file'];
            $fileCount = count($myFile["name"]);

            for ($i = 0; $i < $fileCount; $i++) {
                ?>
                    <p>File #<?= $i+1 ?>:</p>
                    <p>
                        Name: <?= $myFile["name"][$i] ?><br>
                        Temporary file: <?= $myFile["tmp_name"][$i] ?><br>
                        Type: <?= $myFile["type"][$i] ?><br>
                        Size: <?= $myFile["size"][$i] ?><br>
                        Error: <?= $myFile["error"][$i] ?><br>
                    </p>
                <?php
            }
        }
    ?>
</body>
```